# Python class unintentional singleton

Tags: python, singleton

So I've got this code:

```
    # The Headers class is like a dictionary but is able to store multiple name-value pairs with the same name
class Headers:
    def __init__( self, index = [] ):
        self.index = index

    def __contains__( self, name ):
        for own_name, value in self.index:
            if name.lower() == own_name.lower():
                return True
        return False

    def __getitem__( self, name ):
        for i in range( len( self.index ) ):
            if name.lower() == self.index[i][0].lower():
                return self.index[i][1]

    def __iter__( self ):
        return HeadersIterator( self )

    def __setitem__( self, name, value ):
        for i in range( len( self.index ) ):
            if name.lower() == self.index[i][0].lower():
                self.index[i][1] = value

    def add( self, name, value ):
        self.index.append( (name, value) )

class HeadersIterator:
    def __init__( self, headers, index = 0 ):
        self.headers = headers
        self.index = index

    def __next__( self ):
        if self.index >= len( self.headers.index ):
            raise StopIteration()

        result = self.headers.index[ self.index ]
        self.index += 1

        return result
```

I just have this problem with it that when I try to use it, it seems to act as if it where a singleton. Here is some other code that shows I I use it:

```
def headers( self ):
        hs = Headers()
        print("huh?", Headers, hs.index, )

        # Most headers start with HTTP_
        for name, value in self.environ.items():
            if name.startswith( 'HTTP_' ):
                parts = [ (x[0].upper() + x[1:].lower()) for x in name[ len('HTTP_') : ].split( '_' ) ]

                hs.add( '-'.join( parts ), value )

        # Some don't
        if 'CONTENT_LENGTH' in self.environ:
            hs.add('Content-Length', str(self.environ['CONTENT_LENGTH']) )

        return hs
```

Now it seems that the second time it prints the "huh?" line, it seems the hs variable points to the same Headers object, meaning it will only keep adding to the same Headers variable which it returns having even more entries the next time.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: No the list is always the same.

Comment: Might have to do with this: `index = [] ):`. I know using a defaulted list can cause problems since they're mutable.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge: I'm not sure this will solve anything since in that case the **reference of `[][:]` will be copied**...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Header` itself is **not a singleton**, but they refer all to the **same `index`**. This is due to the constructor:

```
def __init__( self, index = []):
    # ...
```

This means that Python constructs **one list** and for each constructor call without a given `index`, a reference to **the same list** is given.

You can solve it by passing an immutable (for instance `None`) and then use an `if` statement and construct a new list like:

```
def __init__( self, index = None):
    if index is None:
        index = []
    # ...
```

Although there are definitely scenarios where it is useful to pass a global reference to the constructor (like you do here), it is advisable to use mutuable objects as defaults with care: always consider passing immutables (like `42`, `None`, `'foobar'`, `True`, `()`,...).

Comment: Ah thanks, I already noticed with some playing around that the problem ceised to exist when I removed the default parameter. Now I know why. Thanks.